# How to get label name from labels in Meta class Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

In Meta class, I define label name for fields. I want to get label name, I tried but nothing.

## forms.py

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['first_name']
    widgets = {
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'text', 'placeholder': 'First Name', 'class': 'form-control input-md'})
    }
    labels = {
        'first_name': "First Name"
    }
```

## views.py

```
def profile(request):
user = UserForm()
user_info = ProfileForm()
return render(request, 'pages/demo.html', {'user': user})
```

## demo.html

```
<label style="margin-left: -48px; margin-right: 48px;" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ ??? }}</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply get it by [**`{{ field.label_tag }}`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.label_tag). For example if you are iterating over form fields:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or if you are manually rendering fields, then you can do it like this:

```
<label style="margin-left: -48px; margin-right: 48px;" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ user.first_name.label }}</label>
```

FYI, I strongly recommend you to rename the context variable from user to anything else(for example you can use `user_form`). Because it will clash with [**`django's auth user`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates) template context.